# OpenRAVE ChechCollison command in C++

Tags: motion-planning, algorithm

What is the equivalent code of "env.CheckCollision(robot)" in C++? Even though it is said that conversion of commands from python to c++ is easy and intuitive, where can I find a proper documentation for this conversion?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out [this example](http://openrave.org/docs/0.8.0/coreapihtml/orcollision_8cpp-example.html) ?

It illustrates checking for self-collisions. If you also have a look at the [`CollisionCheckerBase` class](http://openrave.org/docs/0.8.0/coreapihtml/classOpenRAVE_1_1CollisionCheckerBase.html#acef0a7a968822b61844cb4a0e48f1afc) you can find `OpenRAVE::CollisionCheckerBase::CheckCollision` to check for collisions between two bodies, among other methods. Maybe that is enough to put the pieces together.